# Passing timing value for XYPlot

Tags: java, jfreechart, long-integer

I a have problem while using `getTime()`. The method is passing from another class and using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Can someone help me? I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
panelGraph = new JPanel();
panelGraph.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

aesDataset = XYDataset(caes.getTimeTotal());

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
    "Graph: Encrypted Result", "SetFile", "Time", aesDataset, true, true, false);

chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.green);
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));

XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);

NumberAxis yAxis1 = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis1.setTickLabelPaint(Color.red);

ChartPanel frame1 = new ChartPanel(chart);
frame1.setSize(400, 300);
panelGraph.add(frame1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();` instead of `XYDataset`.
Then add to the dataset TimeSeries as `dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);`  where timeSeries is an object with list of `TimeSeriesDataItem`.